# Rails resource is being created successfully through activeadmin, yet the new or create action is not defined in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a rails project I've inherited and there exists a resource Lessons that is defined in ActiveAdmin where I am able to create a new lesson without a problem. However, the respective controller does not have any of the common default rails actions defined but instead custom ones.

Additionally the controller is of type

```
Lessons < ApplicationController
```

and not

```
Lessons < InheritedResources
```

since InheritedResources hides the common actions, that would make sense.

Does ActiveAdmin know to use those basic create, update, and delete actions behind the scenes if they aren't explicitly defined in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveAdmin` has dependency with `inherited_resources` and could use it even if you don't have this gem in gemfile.

Comment: So if the create action isn't in the controller and it's successfully creating a new lesson resource, it's because it still has access to it from inherited_resources?

Comment: `ActiveAdmin` is engin(http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) which has own structure etc. How change some controller actions you could look http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html